# Query to find the FIRST AND SECOND largest value from a group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT
 DATEPART(year,some_date),
 DATEPART(month,some_date),
 MAX(some_value) max_value
FROM
 some_table
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(year,some_date),
    DATEPART(month,some_date)
```

This returns a table with: *year, month, the largest value for the month*.

I would like to modify the query so that i could obtain:
*year, month, the largest value for the month, **the second largest value for the month*** in each row.

It seems to me that the well-known solutions like "TOP 2", "NOT IN TOP 1" or a subselect won't work here.

(To be really specific - i am using SQL Server 2008.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the question calls for a query that would return best, and second best in the same row for each month and year, like so:

```
month, year, best, second best
...
...
```

and not two rows for the same month and year containing best and second best value.

This is the solution that I came up with, so if anyone has a simpler way of achieving this, I would like to know.

```
with ranks as (
    select 
        year(entrydate) as [year], 
        month(entrydate) as [month], 
        views, 
        rank() over (partition by year(entrydate), month(entrydate) order by views desc) as [rank]
    from product
)
select 
    t1.year, 
    t1.month, 
    t1.views as [best], 
    t2.views as [second best]
from ranks t1
    inner join ranks t2
        on t1.year = t2.year
        and t1.month = t2.month
        and t1.rank = 1
        and t2.rank = 2
```

EDIT: Just out of curiosity I did a bit more testing and ended up with a simpler variation on the [Stephanie Page's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440598/query-to-find-the-first-and-second-largest-value-from-a-group/4443936#4443936) that doesn't use an aditional subquery. And I changed the rank() function to row_number() as it doesn't work when two max values are the same.

```
with ranks as (
    select 
        year(entrydate) as [year], 
        month(entrydate) as [month], 
        views, 
        row_number() over (partition by year(entrydate), month(entrydate) order by views desc) as [rank]
    from product
)
select 
    t1.year, 
    t1.month, 
    max(case when t1.rank = 1 then t1.views else 0 end) as [best], 
    max(case when t1.rank = 2 then t1.views else 0 end) as [second best]
from 
    ranks t1
where
    t1.rank in (1,2)
group by
    t1.year, t1.month
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a working solution, thx. 
I think there are several similar solutions using joins, but i am still wondering (or better said, just curious) if there is one without them?

Comment: I came accross similar problems over the years and was also wondering if there is a simpler solution (without joins maybe), but couldn't fine one. And as it turns out the join solution, although it may seem like a kludge, work perfectly and fast enough.

Comment: @Helena: btw vote and/or accept the answer if you think it is useful, and welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Btw there is a small problem with your solution: if the first and the second highest values are the same in one month, then the corresponding row does not appear in the resultset at all. It is because rank 2 does not exist in such case - the ranks are, e.g., 1,1,3,4,... Using ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK() seems to fix it.

Comment: @Helena: you are right, I was thinking about what will happen when both values are the same but it slipped my mind when I was testing it - and yes, it sounds like ROW_NUMBER should fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

`RANK()` is maybe the thing you are looking for...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: how would you get the desired result using rank()?

Comment: @skajfes: see my response and replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` :-)

Answer (score 2):

to do this without joins ( I'll show the Oracle... you'll just use CASE instead of DECODES)

```
with ranks as (
        select 
            year(entrydate) as [year], 
            month(entrydate) as [month], 
            views, 
            rank() over (partition by year(entrydate), month(entrydate) order by views desc) as [rank]
        from product
    )
SELECT [year], [month], Max([best]), Max([second best])
 FROM
    ( select 
        t1.year, 
        t1.month, 
        Decode([rank],1,t1.views,0) as [best], 
        Decode([rank],2,t1.views,0)  as [second best]
    from ranks t1
    where t1.rank <= 2 ) x
GROUP BY [year], [month]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old-school but TOP and a subquery will work if you use ORDER BY. Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2
 DATEPART(year,some_date),
 DATEPART(month,some_date),
 (SELECT MAX(st1.some_value) FROM some_table AS st1 
  WHERE DATEPART(month,some_date) = DATEPART(month,st1.some_date)) AS max_value
FROM
 some_table
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(year,some_date),
    DATEPART(month,some_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(month,some_date) DESC
```

That will give you the two rows with the "highest" month values and the added subselect should give you the max from each grouping.

Comment: he wants the Max value and the penultimate max value.

Comment: @Stephanie: Please see my update. It took me a few reads through the OP to figure that part out.

Comment: Luckily I was able to change it back

Comment: @Stephanie: Much appreciated. No upvote for some old-school SQL though?

Comment: I'm as big a fan of CTEs and all Sql Server 2005+ goodies as any data geek but i think my solution has some merits like: portability/applicability to other systems (just the TOP keyword would have to be modified), clearer intent to a non-Sql Server person etc. Bottom line is that a vanilla solution to an interesting problem, though not as exciting, could be of greater general interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE with the ranking functions in SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
;WITH TopValues AS
(
   SELECT
     YEAR(some_date) AS 'Year',
     MONTH(some_date) AS 'Month',
     Some_Value,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(some_date),MONTH(some_date) 
                       ORDER BY Some_Value DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
  FROM
     dbo.some_table
)
SELECT
    Year, Month, Some_Value
FROM
    TopValues
WHERE
    RowNumber <= 2
```

This will "partition" (i.e. group) your data by month/year, order inside each group by `Some_Value` descending (largest first), and then you can select the first two of each group from that CTE.

`RANK()` works as well (I most often use `ROW_NUMBER`) - it produces slightly different results, though - really depends on what your needs are.

Comment: gives you both values, but not in the same row.

Comment: @Stephanie Page: I didn't see this as a requirement - but yes, that's true - it would list the top two values separately, each in a separate row of data

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm it's kind of a rig, but you can do this with subqueries... instead of using that max I'd select the some_values which have the matching year & month, row_number()=1 / row_number() = 2 respectively and order by some_value DESC.

The inability to use OFFSET / LIMIT like you can in SQLite is one of my dislikes about SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server 2011 will **have** OFFSET and LIMIT - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: @marc_s: finally, about ten years too late if you ask me